# Rest reading a long using @QueryParam always returns 0 when using @POST

Tags: jquery, rest, post, resteasy

I send the following ajax call to my JBoss server (using jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/services/v1/online/123/abc",
  data: {
    "status": 100
  },
  contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"",
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { },
  error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { },
  dataType: "xml"
});
```

My Java code looks like this (@ApplicationPath and class- @Path is setup correctly so the following is triggered):

```
@POST
@Path("/{docId}/{secId}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String getSectionAccess(@PathParam("docId") String docId,
                               @PathParam("secId") String secId,
                               @QueryParam("status") long timeInMS) {
  System.out.println(timeInMS);
}
```

My problem is that the timeInMS always returns the value 0. If I use @GET instead of @POST then timeInMS equals 100 as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

The following code:

```
ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(HttpServletRequest.class).getParameter("status");
```

shows me that the result of status is "100" (a string but can be converted to a long)... Why is the value not inserted in the timeInMS when using @POST (or @PUT for that matter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the annotation `@QueryParam("status")` to `@FormParam("status")`. Then change the `contentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Or change the `url` to `http://localhost/services/v1/online/123/abc?status=100`

Comment: Thank you very much. For some reason it is a QueryParam when using GET in jQuery and FormParam when using POST or PUT